# PHP for / while loop - Calculate dates based on starting date and interval

Tags: php, for-loop, while-loop

I've got two fields in my database, a `start_date` and an `interval`. Based on these values, I want to calculate other dates. For example:

To keep it simple, the `start_date` is january 1st. The interval is 3. This means that each time the date month should be incremented with 3. The end result should be:

```
01-01 // 1st of january
01-04 // 1st of april
01-07 // 1st of july
01-10 // 1st of october
```

Another example. The `start_date` is may 3rd. The interval is 6. The end result should be:

```
03-05 // 3rd of may
03-11 // 3rd of november
```

I've tried something like this:

```
$interval = 3;

    for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i += $interval)
    {
        echo $start_date->addMonths($i)->format('m-d'); // I'm using carbon
    }
```

But the result is:

```
02-01
05-01
08-01
11-01
```

It first adds `1` from the `$i = 1`, and then it starts the actual loop and adds 3 each time. I'm not sure what I should use for `$i = 1`, or if this can be done with a for loop at all. Any tips?

PS. The starting date can be anything, and the interval can be anything from 1 to 12.

Comment: Your interval isn't working. From January to March, there's 2 months difference. But from March to June and from June to September, there's 3 months.

Comment: That was just me posting an example and I did it wrong.

Comment: What is wrong? My code? Yes, it's why I'm posting here..

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, not you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$start_date = strtotime("2017-05-03");
$interval = 6;
for ($i = 0; $i <= 12; $i += $interval) {
   echo nl2br(date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+" . $i . " month", $start_date)) . "\n");
}
```

Output:

```
2017-05-03
2017-11-03
2018-05-03
```

Comment: Better solution than mine :) Thnx

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it like this:

```
    for ($i = $interval; $i <= 12; $i += $interval)
    {
        echo $start_date->addMonths($i);
    }
```